# Remote sensing software options for creating structure footprints from aerials

Tags: remote-sensing, software-recommendations

As shown in [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDOZJ.jpg) here, just wondering what other software options for creating polygons based on structure footprints are available.

Something cheaper than ENVI but still versatile would be ideal. Typically need a swath of about 1000 feet on either side of polyline ranging from 1 to 1000 miles.

It has been about a year since a similar question was [asked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/which-tools-do-you-use-for-classification-of-remote-sensing-data) and thought there might be some new technology around now.

same screen shot as in above link attached here:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have ArcGIS then check out [Feature Analyst](http://www.overwatch.com/products/feature_analyst.php).  It is not too expensive and does well at extracting out features.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is going to be tricky to do with any classification algorithm (unless it is very specialised or trained to the particular task that you want). However, with minimal user input you can do these sort of things quite efficiently with OTB or Monteverdi. Here's [a presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/melaneum/object-counting-in-high-resolution-remote-sensing-images-with-otb) that you may find useful.